# Узнать все зависимые заголовочные файлы для проекта

Tags: c++, boost, project

Допустим есть проект на С++ который использует Boost::Algorithm::String.hpp. String.hpp в свою очередь использует другие заголовки из Boost и тд. Мне необходимо собрать все эти зависимые файлы в отдельную директорию для поставки с исходным кодом, на тот случай если у пользователя нету Boost библиотеки. Какие есть инструменты для таких задач?

Comment: Почему бы явно не указать в документации к проекту его зависимости? Ладно, если все они будут `header-only`, а если что-то надо будет компилировать в библиотеку, потом ее где-то размещать. Пусть пользователь сам об это позаботится.

Comment: @user207200 Да, на данный момент все так и есть как вы описали. Но, как минимум ради любопытства, хотелось бы узнать и о других вариантах. А на практике, допустим мы хотим передать небольшой скетч, в котором действительно только  `header-only`  библиотеки и чтобы не скидывать все заголовки(их там порядка 14к)

Comment: если это буст, то легче просто сказать "нужен буст, тестил на такой то версии" и не заниматься "выдергиванием".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выделения используемых файлов boost, есть утилита bcp https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html .

Альтернативный способ - скомпилировать проект с трассировкой всех включаемых заголовочных файлов. (Ключи -M и -MM для gcc, /showIncludes для msvc.) Однако, для сложных библиотек (например, boost) этот способ может не работать: список включаемых файлов зависит от компилятора (иногда от опций компилятора) при сборке проекта. Поэтому первый способ - предпочтительнее.